# Swift 3 - How to access a property list

Tags: ios, dictionary, properties, swift3, plist

This is from a property list I created:
[image: property list]

I want to load just the country names into an array. Here's the code I have so far...

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "flagData", ofType: "plist") {
    dict = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)

    let currentGroup = (dict!["caribbean"] as AnyObject).allKeys as? [String]
}
```

But that doesn't work - when I run it, currentGroup = nil

I also tried:

```
let currentGroup = dict?.allKeys(for: "caribbean")
```

But that gives me an empty array.

Any ideas will be appreciated... Thanks!

Comment: What about `dict` itself. Is that nil or does it actually contain data?

Comment: If `dict` isn't `nil`, log `dict.allKeys`. Does it include the key `"caribbean"`?

Comment: dict does contain data and dict.allKeys does include "caribbean"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "flagData", ofType: "plist"),
            let configurations = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) {
                variables = configurations[currentConfiguration] as! NSDictionary
        }
```

Try the above code and make relevant changes i think error in your code is while you cast its failing.

Comment: The cast was the problem exactly! I tried AnyObject and [String:AnyObject] which I thought covered all the bases, but obviously not. Thank you!